# "Change-of-base" between enriched categories

Tags: reference-request, monoidal-categories

I would like to prove that a monoidal functor $$\Phi\colon \mathbf{V}\to \mathbf{V'}$$ induces a functor $$\Phi^\#\colon \mathbf{V}\text{-Cat}\to \mathbf{V'}\text{-Cat}$$

and in particular I would like to check that if $\Phi$ admits a left/right adjoint, then $\Phi^\#$ admits one too. The problem is that I'm stuck in finding the "right" definitions involved (especially that of monoidal functor); I have to silently suppose that $\Phi$ is strong (or "non-lax") monoidal, i.e. $\Phi(A\otimes B)\cong \Phi(A)\otimes '\Phi(B)$, $\Phi(I)\cong I'$ for all $A,B\in \mathbf{V}$ and the "initial" objects $I\in \mathbf V$, $I'\in \mathbf V'$. Such a restrictive assumption leaves me unsatisfied, but I'm not really keen on non-strict monoidal functors...

As a side question, it seems to me this is a well-established result in enriched category theory, but I'm not able to find a precise reference proving the result from the beginning:  Kelly treats the result as a well known folklore, saying in the first pages of *Basic concepts of ECT*

> [we do not] discuss the *change of base-category* given by a symmetric monoidal functor $\mathbf{V}\to \mathbf{V'}$ and the induced 2-functor $\mathbf{V}\text{-Cat}\to \mathbf{V'}\text{-Cat}, [...]$

and John Gray, in his article *Closed Categories, Lax Limits and Homotopy Limits* just gives a statement of the claim I would like to prove. Again, can you help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The change of base is a 2-functor $\mathbf{CBase}:\mathbf{MonCat}\rightarrow\mathbf{2\text{-}Cat}$, so if you have an adjunction in $\mathbf{MonCat}$, you must have an adjunction in $\mathbf{2\text{-}Cat}$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you'll find the following article helpful:

[***Change of Base, Cauchy Completeness and Reversibility*** (pdf)](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/TAC/volumes/10/10/10-10.pdf)

(In A. Labella & V. Schmitt, *Theory and Applications of Categories*, Vol. 10: 10, 2002, pp. 187–219.)

This linked article addresses much of what you're looking for, and includes references which may be of help to you. (E.g. G.M. Kelly, *Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory*, London Mathematical Society Lecture Notes Series 64, Cambridge University Press, 1982.)

Answer (score 3):

The first part of your first question (the existence of the $2$-functor $\Phi^\sharp$) can be found in Borceux's "Handbook of categorical algebra", vol 2, proposition 6.4.3. Notice that Borceux's monoidal functors are lax ones.

Comment: Thanks, I already found it but I think it's nothing difficult to define $\Phi^\#$... the real problem by now seems to be "What is an adjunction between two 2-categories?"

Answer (score 0):

Another really good (and very readable) reference on this is Geoff Cruttwell's thesis:

[G. S. H. Cruttwell, ‘Normed Spaces and the Change of Base for Enriched Categories’](https://www.reluctantm.com/gcruttw/publications/thesis4.pdf)

Chapter 4 explicitly gives these constructions in detail. In particular, you need a *monoidal* adjunction to induce an adjunction between $\mathbf{V}$-$\mathrm{Cat}$ and $\mathbf{V}^\prime$-$\mathrm{Cat}$. However, a functor has a monoidal right adjoint if and only if it is strong monoidal and has a right adjoint functor in the ordinary sense. This will subsume all Cartesian (i.e. product-preserving) functors which admit right adjoints for example.